# Carbon how I can display the day of week in Greek?

Tags: php, php-carbon

Using the following code I try to display a locale into Greek:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

Carbon::setLocale('gr');
echo Carbon::now()->format("l d/m/Y");
```

But the output is:

```
Wednesday 08/12/2021
```

Instead of:

```
Τετάρτη 08/12/2021
```

I also tried the following:

```
Carbon::setLocale('el');
```

Instead of:

```
Carbon::setLocale('gr');
```

But I got the same output as well. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: As noted in the duplicate link (the highest voted, not the accepted answer), you want to use `translatedFormat` instead of `format`. I was able to get the format with `el` instead of `gr`.

Comment: That was it! Idt did the job.